# Laravel validation throwing route error

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

I am attempting a basic validation check on form fields in the controller. The code is below:

```
                $validator = Validator::make(
            array('email' => 'required|min:7'),
            array('password' => 'required|min:7'),
            array('firstName' => 'required'),
            array('lastName' => 'required'));

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            // The given data did not pass validation
            /*Get error msgs from validator*/

           return Redirect::to('members.registration')->withErrors($validator);

        }
```

The parameter passed to Redirect::to here is the folder members and registration view which resides in it. The problem is being caused by this line specifically:

```
   return Redirect::to('members.registration')->withErrors($validator);
```

When it is commented out, form submission returns a blank white page. Otherwise the following error in the picture is shown[image]

The route file has the following content:

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@index');
Route::get('membersaccess', array('as' => 'membersaccess', 'uses' => 'MainController@loadMembersAccess'));
Route::get('signin', array('as' => 'signin', 'uses' => 'MembersController@loadlogin'));
Route::get('signup', array('as' => 'signup', 'uses' => 'MembersController@loadRegistration'));
Route::post('postLogin', array('as' => 'postLogin', 'uses' => 'MembersController@login'));
Route::post('postRegistration', array('as' => 'postRegistration', 'uses' => 'MembersController@registration'));
```

function containing the validation part is:

```
public function registration()
    {
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $password = md5(Input::get('password'));
        $firstName = Input::get('firstName');
        $lastName = Input::get('lastName');
        $country = Input::get('country');

        //echo $email;

        $validator = Validator::make(
            array('email' => 'required|min:7'),
            array('password' => 'required|min:7'),
            array('firstName' => 'required'),
            array('lastName' => 'required'));

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            // The given data did not pass validation
            /*Get error msgs from validator*/

           return Redirect::to('members.registration')->withErrors($validator);

        }
    }
```

and the form for reference:

```
@if(Session::has('errors'))
    <? $errors = Session::get('errors'); ?>
        <h3> {{ $errors->first('email') }}</h3>
@endif

{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'postRegistration')) }}

{{ Form::text('email', null, array('placeholder'=>'Email', 'class' => 'randomfieldsize' ) ) }}
{{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder'=>'Password', 'class'=>'randomfieldsize' ) ) }}
{{ Form::text('firstname', null, array('placeholder'=>'First Name', 'class' => 'randomfieldsize' ) ) }}
{{ Form::text('lastName', null, array('placeholder'=>'Last Name', 'class' => 'randomfieldsize' ) ) }}   
{{ Form::select('country', array('' => '', 'saudi' => 'Saudi Arabia', 'uae' => 'UAE')) }} <br><br>


{{Form::submit('Proceed', ['class' => 'button [radius round]'])}}


{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return Redirect::route('signup')->withErrors($validator);
```

You have no route defined as **members.registration**, so that may be the problem.

To show errors I usually use this (styling with bootstrap):

```
@if( $errors->has() )
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <ul>
    @foreach ( $errors->all('<li>:message</li>') as $error )
        {{ $error }}
    @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Edit: Ugh, didn't noticed it before, but your validation code is wrong. Please refer to http://laravel.com/docs/validation It should be something like this:

```
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $password = Input::get('password'); // Better to hash the password in another place, since md5 can create a hash even of an empty string. Also, please use laravel hash utility instead of md5: http://laravel.com/docs/security#storing-passwords
    $firstName = Input::get('firstName');
    $lastName = Input::get('lastName');
    $country = Input::get('country');

    $validator = Validator::make(
        compact('email', 'password', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'country'),
        array(
            'email' => 'required|min:7',
            'password' => 'required|min:7'
            'firstName' => 'required'
            'lastName' => 'required'
        ));
```

Comment: I did that change and now when I submit the form (empty or not) it just reloads to empty with no errors. I guess something is still wrong because those errors are not showing yet.

Comment: Note that when I put echo "error"; inside the @if condition in the view, it actually prints that but not the errors related to validation rules. Any idea why?

Comment: I tried it an it only prints one validation error which is password. I thought with the foreach you used it would print all of them.

Comment: Edited my answer again. That should fix it.